# Python - Bs4 regex matching results into []

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I used regextester101 to confirm that my regex is not incorrect as it does find a match for one of the following ids in the HTML page which is:         `pj_8c1bde71686c6c05`

Page I am trying to scrape: http://www.indeed.ca/help-desk-jobs-in-ON

ID I am using as a test from the html file: `pj_8c1bde71686c6c05`

```
bs4 = BeautifulSoup(search_result_contents, "html.parser")
result = bs4.find_all('div', re.compile('id_=p\w*_\w*'))
print(result)
```

Result prints out:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: You have an underscore after `id=` in your regex which doesn't seem to actually appear in the page.

Comment: Ah didn't notice that! I removed it but im still getting the same results :/

Comment: @FiendBusa also updated with an alternative option - a CSS selector. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you, it works but for some reason im only getting 3 results even when the html page has more than 3 that match the regex and your css selector. Edit:nvm it works thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `id` argument if you want regex to be applied to the `id` attribute. Also, you need to use a "raw" string and fix your regular expression:

```
bs4.find_all('div', id=re.compile(r'pj_\w+'))
```

Here `pj_\w+` would match `pj`, followed by underscore, followed by one or more alphanumeric characters.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> url = "http://www.indeed.ca/help-desk-jobs-in-ON"
>>> 
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
>>> soup.find_all('div', id=re.compile(r'pj_\w+'))
[<div class="row result" data-jk="13fdade4fb44d84f" id="pj_13fdade4fb44d84f">\n...
>\n</div>\n<span class="sdn">Sponsored</span>\n</br></div>]
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the "starts-with" [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
bs4.select("div[id^=pj_]")
```

Comment: Do you know why I only get 3 results even when the html page has more than 3 matching the regex?Edit:nvm it works thanks!

Comment: @FiendBusa actually, I see the consistency there. If I execute `$$("div[id^=pj_]").length` in the browser console - I get 5. If I execute `len(BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser").select("div[id^=pj_]"))` - I also get 5..

Comment: Yup, its because all the results are in one element. Not sure what determines the creation of more. all the ids matching the regex are present but they are just in one line.

Comment: @FiendBusa okay, what are you trying to extract from this page?

Comment: Interestingly I get completely different source code returned with requests and my browser.

Comment: Im trying to extract all the jobs on the front page. I was able to split the jobs into different elements. Thanks for all the help.